# nodemcu Docker build environment

Tags: docker, nodemcu

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have Docker installed.

`docker run hello-world` works correctly.

I want to use Marcel's nodeMCU docker build environment.

I've cloned nodemcu-firmware from GitHub.

```
cd ~/Desktop

git clone https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware.git

cd nodemcu-firmware
```

Now let's fire up the Docker image. The compilation seems to work, I think?

```
docker run --rm -ti -v `pwd`:/opt/nodemcu-firmware marcelstoer/nodemcu-build

/* snip */
make[2]: Entering directory '/opt/nodemcu-firmware/tools/spiffsimg'
make[2]: 'spiffsimg' is up to date.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/opt/nodemcu-firmware/tools/spiffsimg'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/nodemcu-firmware/tools'
```

But I can't find where the output firmware binary goes.

Where does it go?
Am I running this correctly?

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                  TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
hello-world                 latest              e38bc07ac18e        3 weeks ago         1.85 kB
marcelstoer/nodemcu-build   latest              9a64aec23caa        3 weeks ago         373 MB
ubuntu                      14.04               67759a80360c        4 months ago        221 MB

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS      

    PORTS               NAMES
```

Comment: Which docker image are you intalling? You've told that you had Ubuntu 16.04 but I suppose that this Ubuntu is your host system, not docker.
Could yout post `docker images`and `docker ps` output, please?

Comment: it's marcelstoer/nodemcu-build pulled from dockerhub as you can see.

Comment: OP edited above with docker images and ps output. ps outputs nothing.

Comment: Try `docker run -ti -v \`pwd\`:/opt/nodemcu-firmware marcelstoer/nodemcu-build marcelstoer/nodemcu-build bash` and you'll be using shell inside without having executed entry point. Then, execute binary or look it up

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation of the image on dockerhub says, the output binaries are stored in your present working directory where you run `docker run ...` command. You set it to `pwd` after `-v` flag.

> The two firmware files (integer and float) are created in the bin sub folder of your NodeMCU root directory. You will also find a mapfile in the bin folder with the same name as the firmware file but with a .map ending.

For example, if you run `docker run ...` command in `/home/` directory, you should be able to find the binaries in `/home/bin` on your host machine if there's no error in the execution of the docker container.